# Word for one who does not see flaw/fault in oneself?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, meaning-in-context, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I have been digging for a word that English seems to have a hard time representing.  If I were to describe the spirit of what I'm trying to convey, it would be one who does not look inward for fault or error.  It's a confidence, a self-belief, perhaps even a self confidence.

The issue I have when trying to isolate a word like this is that often the suggestion is far harsher than what I visualize. The suggestions I get seem to be rooted in arrogance, without blame, or words that suggest a supreme confidence. Instead I'm trying to convey a sort of organic confidence in oneself.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a big difference between *confidence* and *overconfidence*. When you describe somebody who *never* looks inward, that's negative trait. The lack of self-awareness or self-reflection is rarely seen as something positive. Which is why you would have found words such as *arrogance*. Or *overconfidence*. It sounds like you're looking for someone who *is* self-aware and inward looking but who doesn't *doubt* themselves when they act. (*Because* they know who they are.) So, I'm not sure why you rejected the words at the end of your first paragraph . . .

Answer (score 1):

The word you are undoubtedly seeking is ***aplomb***. I refer to senses 2 and 3 of the OED entry below.

> Etymology: French aplomb perpendicular position, steadfastness,
>   assurance, < the phrase à plomb ‘according to the plummet.’
>
> 1. ‘The perpendicular’; perpendicularity. 1872   C. King Mountaineering in Sierra Nevada iii. 69   We sprang on, never resting
>      long enough to lose the aplomb.
>
> 1880   A. D. Whitney Odd or Even? iii. 23   The girl jumped, with
>   clean aplomb, from the wagon-wheel to the broad door-stone. (Hide
>   quotations)
>
> 2. Assurance, confidence, self-possession, coolness. 1828   T. P. Thompson Exercises (1842) IV. 548   They never present themselves with
>      any aplomb; but always with some lurking recognition of the power of
>      their adversaries.
>
> 1849   C. Brontë Shirley I. xi. 291   Impatience of her chilly
>   ceremony, and annoyance at her want of aplomb.
>
> 3. attrib. quasi-adj. Self-possessed, confident. 1865   A. D. Whitney Gayworthys 220   Her ordinary, aplomb fashion of speech.

Answer (score -2):

The word conceited could be used.

> con·ceit·ed
>
> kənˈsēdəd
>
> adjective
>
> excessively proud of oneself; vain.
>   synonyms:   vain, narcissistic, self-centered, egotistic, egotistical, egocentric

Comment: You seem to be quoting a dictionary definition.  If so, please identify it by name and link to it.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.